# How do I determine processor speed required for optical flow?

Tags: specifications, microprocessors, opticalflow

I'd like to use an optical flow system to get velocities from surrounding environment. I've read papers about how optical flow works, but they don't treat details about optic sensors.

My question is: How do I determine how much computational power is required to perform optical flow analysis?

I'd like to use a low-power system (like microcontrollers), but I don't know what kind of camera I could use with such a system. I mean, could it be color or does it need to be B/W? Rolling shutter or global shutter? Which frame rate or number of pixels?

I'd like to specify the system myself but, without knowing how those camera attributes impact the processing load, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I think this question would be better posed if you asked, "How do I determine how much computational power is required to perform optical flow analysis?" Then, with a description of how the process works, you could work backwards and determine what camera you could use. This is 1 of the 2 methods generally used in engineering - start with the equipment and move forward ("If you have a motor of size X you can go speed Y") or start with the end specification and work backwards ("If you want to go speed Y you need a motor of size X"). You're trying to do the latter - Processor Y needs camera X.

Comment: In  fact, as I wrote that, I thought, "This sounds like a question about how much processor is required to run some software," which then made me think it might be better suited for [so]. I checked and they have a tag, "opticalflow", with 222 questions. We don't even have the tag here. I'll edit your question and migrate it for you. Hopefully you'll get some great answers there!

Comment: Hello Stack Overflow! I'm a moderator at [robotics.se] and thought this question would be better suited here. I edited the question for title and tags, but don't have privileges here to push them through. I hope the question is on-topic for you guys and the question gets a lot of great answers! Feel free to delete this comment and the earlier ones; I just hate migrating something without leaving a note to site.

Answer (score 1):

As [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5171120) already said in the comment. You first need to start with something. Opticalflow calculation really depends on what you are using it for and what you are trying to achieve. For realtime applications you might want to consider using faster processors (this is always true though).

Continuing to my answer.

Opticalflow calculation performance depends on few main things:

- The optical-flow **method** you choose (**dense** or **sparse**), you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037136/difference-between-sparse-and-dense-optical-flow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507645/accelerating-opticalflow-algorithm-opencv). Of course that you should take into account not only that sparse is faster than dense, also that sparse might be less accurate in some cases. Again, this depends on what you're trying to achieve.
  In addition, you will see that there are **different optical-flow algorithms**. Some might be faster than others. There are many algorithms such as Lucas-Kanade, Horn-Schunck, TVL1, Farneback, etc.
- Most optical-flow methods from libraries such as OpenCV gives you the ability to change some **parameters** in order to *play* with the trade-off between accuracy and performance. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309567/speeding-up-optical-flow-createoptflow-dualtvl1?rq=1) and also check the OpenCV methods such as [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) for example - see the different arguments.
- The **resolution** of your image. Smaller image usually means faster calculation.

Few things you might also want to consider:

- If you are using a processor that has **multiple cores**, make sure that you are using all the cores in the optical-flow calculation. Some libraries may already do this for you, but in some cases you will need to do it by yourself. Take a look at my question and answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665634/3132173), it might give you some idea and help you getting starting with such case.
- If you want more accurate optical-flow results you **must** use **global shutter** camera. Rolling shutter cameras, such as most of the web-cams, will give you an extra error you don't want.
- You don't need color image, if you have a **grayscale** camera it will be even better. If not, you will need to convert it to grayscale (not B/W) for faster performance as well.
- Some libraries such as OpenCV has an option (in some cases) to run these algorithms on a **GPU**. If using a GPU is an option you might want to consider this as well.

From my own experience, the main thing that gave me a boost in performance was changing my resolution from 640x480 to 320x240 and even 160x120. In my case it didn't really hurt the accuracy.
I used an [Odroid U3](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=g138745696275) mini-pc with [OpenCV PyrLK](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) algorithm and input frames of 320x240 resolution. After applying what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665634/3132173) (splitting the image to 4 for parallel calculation) it worked pretty well (realtime).

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Sarid has some strong points, and many of them are shared by researchers around the world. My opinions are shared by anyone who has actually worked with these topics in the real-world setting.... with real world, i mean implementing optical flow in drones, on mobile phones and IP cameras that are not sitting in a protected office, and where other systems (such as humans) need to interact and be co-dependent.

First of all, depending on your problem, you may want to invest time in looking for ready-made solutions. Optical flow sensors are readily available, cheap and robust (but usually not strong in accuracy). These are the kind of sensors you find in optical mice. They are low power, and easily interfaced with micro-controllers. Some have staggering sample rates of thousands of fps. They commonly have low spatial resolution however, and (to emphasize) high robustness but low accuracy.

If instead you are looking for the kind of optical flow that can be used for shape from motion, pedestrian detection and video-encoding, for example, then you are probably better off to look for something more advanced, and thats where Sarids answer becomes relevant.

Since your question has been migrated from robotics stack exchange, I am going to assume you are interested applications close to machine control and human machine interaction. In that case, the most important aspects are the ones usually most ignored by people working in the field of optical flow estimation, namely:

1. **Latency**. If you have a human interfacing at the front-end... then the common term is "glass-to-glass latency". This is completely different from the fps of your system, which is connected to throughput. If you find that you are in a discussion with someone, and they do not understand the difference between latency and fps, then they are not the expert you are interested in. For example, almost all researchers in computer vision who do GPU implementations of optical flow add massive latency by allowing for frame delays and ineffecient memory handling (inefficient from perspective of latency, but efficient in terms of throughput and hard-ware utilization). Consider the problem of controlling a drone, say make it self-stabilizing, it is better to receive a bad optical flow estimation 10 ms earlier, then a good one with 10 ms extra delay.... especially if the optical system does not give you any upper bounds of the delay for any given time.
2. **Algorithm stability**. This is completely different from accuracy. Accuracy is what 99% of all research in optical flow has been obsessing about for the last 30 years. Stability is not at all something evaluated in the Middlebury benchmark for example. Stability deals with how small changes in your data will guarantee small changes in the estimated optical flow. While some good work has been done in the community (on robust statistics most interestingly) in the end the final evaluation of any algortihm disregards stability. Consider the optical mouse as a good example. The first generations of optical mice had higher accuracy (the average error from the true motion was smaller) but they had lower stability (especially when you ran the mice over "bad textures", with rotational motions). Later generations of optical mouse have worse accuracy, but are focusing on the stability, as that is the most important thing. You dont experience the mouse cursor jumping around as much as you did the earlier days of the devices.... but if you move the mouse on your mat, left and right repeatedly, you will see the cursor slowly drifting (i.e. low accuracy).
3. **Heat**. Any device that will estimate high accuracy optical flow, will require lots of computations. When it comes to computations per watt, GPUs are not that good. In drones, you may be able to get away with this, because it is a setting where you have active cooling as a by-product of the propulsion system. In the real-world, you most often can not assume active cooling nor unlimited power supply.

To conclude, its a fascinating area, and I hope you have a great experience coding solutions.